# Google SRP not showing Mobile breadcrumb

Tags: google-search, mobile, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs

I have implemented schema code for Breadcrumb on mobile site which is same as on Desktop. Now Desktop breadcrumb structure is getting visible on Google SRP, but when i check Mobile breadcrumb structure in Android Phone Google SRP, it is not visible. I have verified both code in schema structure tool.

Is there any different schema code for mobile breadcrumb.

Need any additional information regarding this, please send me your queries.